# How not to include special characters & numeric in Jquery TagIt

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, tag-it

How can i show the special characters(~!@#...etc)  and numeric number(0-9) not in tag when user key in the value from the input tag? Is it possible to restrict special characters and numeric display in normal text? Any help would be appreciated.

Current output : 
[image]

```
    <%
    ArrayList alTag        = new ArrayList();
    Vector vTag             = new Vector();
    String SQL = "SELECT CODE, DESCP FROM TB_FRUIT WITH UR";
    TEST.makeConnection();
    TEST.executeQuery(SQL);
    while(TEST.getNextQuery())
    {
        Vector vRow = new Vector();

        ArrayList alInner   = new ArrayList();
        String field =TEST.getColumnString("CODE");
        String descp =TEST.getColumnString("DESCP");
        alInner.add(field);
        alInner.add(descp);
        alTag.add(alInner);
        vTag.addElement(field);
    }
    TEST.takeDown();
    %>
    <script>
    var dbArray = [<%
                  String dbCode = "";
                  String dbList = "";   
                  for(int i=0;i<vTag.size();i++)
                  {
                    dbCode      = (String) vTag.elementAt(i);
                    dbList      += "\"" + dbCode + "\",";
                  }
                  out.print(dbList); %>
               ];

      $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#myTags").tagit({
        availableTags: dbArray

        });
      });
   </script>
   <html>
   <body> 
       <input type="text" id="myTags" name="TYPE">
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: Hmm.. no solution on this ?

Answer (score 0):

This restricts the  input only to alphabets

```
$('#myTags').keypress(function (event) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z]+$");
    var str = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
    if (!regex.test(str)) {
        e.preventDefault();
         return false;
    }

});
```

If you are open to introducing a jquery plugin, the easiset way is to include the [alphanum jquery plugin] and then do

```
$('#myTags').alpha();
```

[alphanum jquery plugin] : https://github.com/KevinSheedy/jquery.alphanum

**UPDATED :**

You could extent the jquery tagit plugin and override the cleaned input method as shown below so as to replace non alphabets .

```
$.widget( "ui.tagit", $.ui.tagit, {        
    _cleanedInput: function() {
    var cleanedInput = this.tagInput.val().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9\s]+/,"");
    return $.trim(cleanedInput.replace(/^"(.*)"$/, '$1'));
    }
});
```

Comment: Not to restricts the input field, i need to show em's too. Just not showing out them in `tag` mode.